# Java 8: Change the values of an EntrySet stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have the following setup:

```
Map<Instant, String> items;
...
String renderTags(String text) {
    // Renders markup tags in a string to human readable form
}
...
<?> getItems() {
    // Here is where I need help
}
```

My problems is, the strings that are the values of the `items` map are marked up with tags.  I want `getItems()` to return all the items, but with the strings parsed using the `renderTags(String)` method.  Something like:

```
// Doesn't work
items.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.setValue(renderTags(e.getValue())));
```

What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: what do you want the `getItems()` method to return?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  A set of entries would be great, but anything that would allow me to loop over them in the order they are returned (they are stored in a `TreeSet<Instant, String>` so they stay in chronological order).

Comment: Uhm, I think you treat set and map as interchangeable, in fact they differ. A set is basically a map to Boolean, a map is generally not a set.

Comment: @Vlasec You are of course correct.  Maybe it's time I get to bed.  It is only 0215 though, so I think I'm good for a few more hours...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want a `Map` as result:

```
Map<Instant, String> getItems() {
    return items.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> renderTags(e.getValue())));
}
```

Comment: Oh well, you were almost a full minute faster :/

Comment: Can either of you tell me why I'd get a `Cannot resolve method 'getKey'` on the line `Map.Entry::getKey`?

Comment: Are you sure that your `Map` import is really `java.util.Map`?

Comment: @DidierL I just checked to make sure and it is.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.  It was a typo in the method return type, that was somehow showing up as the error I mentioned.  Fixed that and it works great :)

Answer (score 23):

If you want to modify an existing map instead of generating the new one (as in your example), there's no need to use the stream at all. Use `Map.replaceAll`:

```
items.replaceAll((k, v) -> renderTags(v));
return items;
```

If you want to keep the original map unchanged, consult other answers.

Comment: Not what I need here (the new map is just for display purposes), but I didn't know that, so I'll file it away for later.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah this is the solution i needed. if you don't want a new map, use this.

Answer (score 8):

You can try it this way with `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Map<Instant, String> getItems() {
    return items.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            entry -> renderTags(entry.getValue())
                         ));
}
```

By the way, if the name says simply "get", you shouldn't generally transform it in there. One expects a getter to be simple and not costy at all.

Comment: Yep, to the victor go the spoils.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 you can also do:

```
Entry<String, String> entry = Map.entry("a", "b");
```

In your Map it would be used like this:

```
Map<Instant, String> getItems() {
    return items.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), renderTags(entry.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative could be

```
Map<Instant, String> getItems() {
return items.entrySet().stream()
           .peek(entry -> entry.setValue(renderTags(entry.getKey())))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

see [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api)

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing it this way versus the way shown in the accepted answer?

Comment: it depends on context (not the one of the question)... I havn't yet used the peek method but I keep in mind it exists.

Comment: Sounds good.  I use it a lot for debugging (just shooting the result to System.err), but I've never thought to use it like this.

Comment: Me too :) And I havn't been in the case of a sequence of changes to apply to a collection or map.

Comment: What does exactly happen when you modify an entry? I think it changes the map and the action called in peek should be non-interfering. It is good for logs, but if I got it, it shouldn't be used this way, as far as I know.

Comment: You have to think your map with references of objects. Updating the value of an entry doesn't affect the map itself (nor the result of hashcode and equals mechanism used on keys for storing elements).

Comment: And this remark is valid for collections in general. When iterating on a collection, you can update the elements inside. Not the collection itself.

Comment: +1 for giving a solution to alter the original map. Exactly what I was looking for. Note that with the accepted answer it can also work but the original Map must be merged with the altered keys like `oMap.putAll(alteredMap)`. Method peek prevent to do this.

Comment: Don't perform operations in `peek`, they are not guaranteed to execute. It's only for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yes, definitely, I update my answer.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. `peek` should not perform any operation with side effects. It's meant to be used to print intermediate results.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api. the last paragraph describes clearly the same use case in a non debugging context: "we want to alter the inner state of an element". Even if I try to avoid this situation, I conceive it can occurs. That's why I may have used at least once in my carrer.